# Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : invalid first argument. Error al sobrecribir un data.frame en R

Tags: r

Quisiera saber si a alguien más le aparece este problema al sobrescribir o "chancar" una base de datos. Es algo que me ha pasado con la últimas actualizaciones de R y no sé si es parte de ello. Cuando reviso la base de datos resultante no veo mayor problema, pero no sé que tanto pueda estar afectando mis procesos de trabajo. Les adjunto un código de ejemplo y el error completo que suele aparecer:

```
`Data$ConsumPerCap=(Data$vab_1)/(Data$vab_2)`
```

Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) :
invalid first argument
Error in assign(cacheKey, frame, .rs.CachedDataEnv) :
attempt to use zero-length variable name

Comment: Existe la nueva varaible `ConsumPerCap`,? sino vas  tener que hacer `Data["ConsumPerCap"] = (Data$vab_1)/(Data$vab_2)`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho No existe porque lo estoy creando ahí mismo. Ese es el método que siempre he usado para crear una nueva variable en la misma base. Cuando ejecuto el codigo, la variable se crea, pero genera ese error con cualquier otro código que se ejecute sobre la misma base.

Comment: Si es cierto, estaba en modo "python pandas", fijate si no es este bug: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13188